# how to use maven with a computer without internet connection (Windows 7)

Tags: maven, offline

I have found a project using Maven : jest

I have a computer with Microsoft Windows 7 64 without Internet connection.

I use an other one (with Microsoft Windows 7 64 and an internet connection) to get all dependencies. My dependencies are in the folder ".m2".

So I took every file in this directory and I simply do a copy paste to my computer without internet connection.

I have tried :

```
mvn clean

mvn -o clean
```

update settings.xml with

```
<offline>true</offline> and 
<localRepository>pathToMyRepository</localRepository>
```

Adding this to my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Did I miss something ?

if I execute mvn -o clean :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testJest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 is mis
sing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.063 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-29T11:25:28+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dep
endencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apach
e.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-cl
ean-plugin:jar:2.5 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

Comment: *maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5* note the version.

Comment: so I have to use this ?? <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: 2.5 and look into .m2 if you have it.

Comment: Have you considered running a local Maven repository? I run Nexus on my laptop which enables me to perform off-line builds. (Nexus caches all binaries pulled down as dependencies).

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: maybe I ll install Nexus, I don't know this product and I need to resolve my problem very quickly...

Comment: That will solve your problems...But you need having at least one time internet access to download all the needed artifacts...like the plugins etc...Furthermore a plugin does not make sense as a dependency....

Comment: you could use the goal: dependency:go-offline - see: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html - this will download all dependencies and plugins to build your project into the local repository. Copying that should then allow to build it on the offline machine as well.

Comment: Thank you very much I solve my problem with -> maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5